# Differentiating this inverse trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

$$\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{2^{x+1}\cdot3^x}{1+36^{x}} \right)$$
Had this question for todays test but still cannot find out how to proceed.

Comment: have you tried the chain rule?

Comment: The derivative of $x \rightarrow sin^{-1}(x)$ is $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $, if this is what got you stuck

Comment: Is there any less cumbersome way like substitutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain a few steps you can use to solve your problem:

1. $$\frac{\text{d}\arcsin(f(x))}{\text{d}x}=\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}}$$
2. When $f(x)=\frac{z(x)}{y(x)}$ we get:
   $$f'(x)=\frac{\text{d}\left(\frac{z(x)}{y(x)}\right)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{y(x)z'(x)-z(x)y'(x)}{y(x)^2}$$
3. When $y(x)=\text{k}+\text{c}^{q(x)}$ we get ($\text{c}$ and $\text{k}$ are constants):
   $$y'(x)=\frac{\text{d}\left(\text{k}+\text{c}^{q(x)}\right)}{\text{d}x}=q'(x)\ln(\text{c})\text{c}^{q(x)}$$
4. When $z(x)=r(x)\cdot v(x)$ we get:
   $$z'(x)=\frac{\text{d}\left(r(x)\cdot v(x)\right)}{\text{d}x}=v(x)r'(x)+r(x)v'(x)$$

Now, you can use:

- $$\frac{\text{d}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}=1$$
- When $\text{a}$ is a constant:
  $$\frac{\text{d}\left(\text{a}\right)}{\text{d}x}=0$$

Answer (score 4):

The function
$$
f(x)=\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2}
$$
is defined for every real $x$, because $|2x|<1+x^2$. We also have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)^2}}
\cdot 2\frac{(1+x^2)-x\cdot 2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=
2\frac{1+x^2}{|1-x^2|}\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$
so
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{1+x^2} & \text{if $|x|<1$} \\[6px]
-\dfrac{2}{1+x^2} & \text{if $|x|>1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus we can write
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
a+2\arctan x & \text{if $|x|<1$} \\[6px]
b-2\arctan x & \text{if $|x|>1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $f(0)=0$, we have $a=0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ we have $b=\pi$. Finally
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2\arctan x & \text{if $|x|\le 1$} \\[6px]
\pi-2\arctan x & \text{if $|x|>1$}
\end{cases}
$$
The function is not differentiable at $-1$ and $1$.

You can now write your complicated function as
$$
g(x)=\arcsin\frac{2^{x+1}\cdot 3^x}{1+36^x}=f(6^x)
$$
by noticing that $2^{x+1}\cdot 3^x=2\cdot 6^x$ and $36^x=(6^x)^2$.

Thus, by the chain rule,
$$
g'(x)=f'(6^x)\cdot 6^x\ln 6
$$
provided $6^x\ne1$, that is, $x\ne0$. Explicitly,
$$
g'(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2\cdot 6^x\cdot \ln 6}{1+36^x} & \text{if $x>0$} \\[6px]
-\dfrac{2\cdot 6^x\cdot \ln 6}{1+36^x} & \text{if $x<0$} \\[6px]
\end{cases}
$$

The function is not differentiable at $0$, as it can be seen in the diagram (and proved directly).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{align}
y&=\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2^{x+1}3^x}{1+36^x}\right)\\
 &=\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2^x\cdot2\cdot3^x}{1+36^x}\right)\\
 &=\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cdot6^x}{1+6^{2x}}\right)\\
&=2\tan ^{-1}6^x
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{2}{1+6^{2x}}\cdot6^x\log 6\\
\implies \frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{2\cdot6^x\log 6}{1+36^x}
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah! This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: This is not true!

Comment: @JanEerland Why ?

Comment: Because $\arcsin\left(\frac{2^{1+x}\cdot3^x}{1+36^x}\right)\ne2\arctan(6)^x$

Comment: @JanEerland We've this identity $$\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right) = 2\tan^{-1}x$$

Comment: @HGSur No that's not true for every value of $x$.

Comment: @HGSur Thank you for posting this, this is the identity I used in line 4 of the algebra.

Comment: I see I am being down voted quite heavily; this is the correct answer, it's frustrating that people are so quick to jump on a bandwagon.

Comment: The identity listed by @HGSur is correct.

Comment: No it is not the correct answer!!!

Comment: @JanEerland I've a doubt : Is that identity applicable for $x\in[\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] $since I am allowed to assume it in the test?

Comment: Using the assumptions you can, but out of the posted boundaries, it is not right!

Comment: @Bacon However $2^{x+1}.3^x\neq2^x+2.3^x\neq2^x.6^x$

Comment: $2^{x+1}.3^x=2.2^x.3^x=2.6^x$ is what you meant.

Comment: @Bacon when your answer is wrong, the downvotes are legal! Ian Miller, pointed out some mistakes, if you change those you're right. But now you're wrong!

Comment: @Bacon Graphing the function clearly shows it can't be increasing as your derivative would imply.

Answer (score 2):

If we have $y = \arcsin(2^{x + 1} 3^x / (1 + 36^x))$, then $$\sin y = \frac{2^{x + 1} 3^x}{1 + 36^x}$$ The expression on the right is still a daunting product/quotient, but it can be reduced to sums/differences using logarithms, giving $$\ln \sin y = (x + 1) \ln 2 + x \ln 3 - \ln(1 + 36^x)$$ Now it is routine to take the derivative with respect to $x$ (remember the chain rule for the left!): $$ \frac{y' \cos y}{\sin y} = \ln 2 + \ln 3 - \frac{36^x \ln(36)}{1 + 36^x} = \ln 6 \left(1 - \frac{2 \cdot 36^x}{1 + 36^x}\right) $$ and solving for $y'$ gives $$ y' = \ln 6 \tan y \left(\frac{1 - 36^x}{1 + 36^x}\right)$$

Comment: Might be daunting, but much better than direct differentiation :)

Answer (score 1):

you need the caine rule and the rule for an exponential function
$$\frac{\frac{2^{x+1} 3^x \log (3)}{36^x+1}+\frac{2^{x+1} 3^x \log (2)}{36^x+1}-\frac{2^{3
   x+1} 27^x \log (36)}{\left(36^x+1\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2^{2 x+2} 3^{2
   x}}{\left(36^x+1\right)^2}}}$$